# How can i add a simple call to open file dialog on headerbar?

Tags: development

Does anybody can tell me how to add a button to call open_file_dialog on GTK Header bar?
i did it in appmenu with,

$.activate.connect(() =>{
                this.dialog_openFile();
            });

but this way dont works on a simple call in headerbar,

i'm a newbie, learning about GTK and Granit.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. First, you'll need a header bar and add a button to it.

```
private void create_headerbar () {
    var headerbar = new Gtk.HeaderBar ();

    var button = new Gtk.Button.from_icon_name ("document-open",
        Gtk.IconSize.LARGE_TOOLBAR);

    button.clicked.connect (() => {
        show_file_dialog();
    });        

    headerbar.pack_start (button);
    window.set_titlebar (headerbar);
}
```

The `window` at the end is a `Gtk.Window` I've declared elsewhere.

That `show_file_dialog()` method is the one that will show the dialog. 
It's declared next:

```
private void show_file_dialog(){
    var dialog = new Gtk.FileChooserDialog ("Open File",
                                  window,
                                  Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                                  "_Cancel",
                                  Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                                  "_Open",
                                  Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT);

    var response = dialog.run();

    if (response == Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT) {
        string filename = dialog.get_filename();

        //now do something with the filename
    }       
    dialog.dispose(); //no need for the dialog to be around anymore
}
```

I think this is a good starting point. You'll need to adapt it for your needs like changing the methods' signatures and so...

"Works on my machine"™